# Multiple identity providers with Office 365 based SharePoint 2013 web application

Tags: authentication, office365, azure-acs

I am trying to get multiple identity providers (Google, Facebook, multiple ADFS)  working with a SharePoint 2013 web application provisioned on Office 365.

I know about options related to ADFS and Shibboleth, but am wondering if there is any way to get Azure ACS to handle the authentication for this web app. I do have an on-premise SharePoint 2013 web application working with Azure ACS, but don’t have much info around how to do the same thing with Office 365 or if it’s even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Not supported (yet).
Given that Office 365 use Windows Azure AD, we can hope that ACS support will come one day.